# How to access Android resource strings from Flutter Plugin

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm building a plugin for Flutter and I want to access the Android app resource strings from the plugin.

I'm trying using:

```java
@Override
    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
        switch (call.method) {
            case "example":
                String value = context.getString(R.string.name);
                result.success(value);
                break;
            default:
                result.notImplemented();
                break;
        }
    }
```

But `R.string` points to the plugin resources, not the app resources.

Regards

Comment: Isn't `R.string` pointing to `strings.xml` file?

Comment: No, its pointing to the plugin resoures class which is not what I want. I want to access to the app resources

Comment: But for me it is pointing to `strings.xml`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad do you have an example?

Answer (score 4):

OK I found a solution.
I got this function from the [Auth0 Android repo](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.Android)

So basically to get app resources from a plugin they use this function

```java
private static String getResourceFromContext(@NonNull Context context, String resName) {
        final int stringRes = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "string", context.getPackageName());
        if (stringRes == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The 'R.string.%s' value it's not defined in your project's resources file.", resName));
        }
        return context.getString(stringRes);
    }
```